# JS function not sending a request

Tags: javascript

This code should work but I'm missing something, how can I debug JS code to know where's the problem? I'm sending a user input (string) to a third party API, I should expect a JSON results in `<p class="score">` Nothing happens!

```
var myurl = 'https://apiv2.indico.io/sentiment';
var api_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';


function ApiRequest() {

    var mydata = document.getElementById('userinput').value;

    $.post(
      myurl,
        JSON.stringify({
        'api_key': api_key,
        'data': mydata,

      }).then(function(sent) { 

        var s = sent
        var obj = JSON.parse(s)

        $('.score').append(obj.results)

 });
```

HTML

```
<input placeholder="I love writing code!" id="userinput">    

<button onclick="ApiRequest" id="submit">Try It</button>

<p class="score">Score : </p>
```

The `userinput` is not passed to the Javascript but it's accessible via `alert`

Comment: What part of you code do you expect to send the request? You don't even use the `api` variable that holds the URL :-?

Comment: @Álvaro-gonzález I updated the question. Thanks!

Comment: You still don't use the `api` variable, but now you have a **string** that contains `'api'` as text. You surely didn't mean that.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález api is a url, a string (text?) I stored it in a variable a it's used in ApiRequest() function. Not sure about the syntax..

Comment: But as @ÁlvaroGonzález says you are posting to a url called 'api' not the url contained in the variable api

Comment: `$.post(
   'api',` ... how about `$.post(
   api,` instead ?

Comment: @jaromanda-x Yeah, you're right. It's working! Do you have any idea on how to pass user input please?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I updated my question..